# Is it possible to accelerate the webgl matrix Multiplication through pnacl?

Tags: javascript, matrix, webgl, google-nativeclient

The poor performance of matrix multiplication in javascript is an obstacle for high performance webgl. So I am thinking about using pnacl to accelerate it.

Ideally, I'd like to pass the ArrayBuffer(Float32Array) and the matrix to pnacl, then use the native code to finish the multiplication and update the value in the buffer, at last notify the page(javascript).

But I am doubt if the buffer memory can be shared for pnacl and page javascript?
If not, I have to pass the buffer back to client, I am not sure the influence of such operation to performance.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PPAPI passes the ArrayBuffer using shared memory, so copying will be minimal.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/proxy/plugin_array_buffer_var.h

However, PNaCl plugins run in a different (plugin) process in Chrome, so latency (time to send the message to the plugin and receive an answer) may negate any performance improvement from native code.

Answer (score 0):

As with all optimization questions, you should profile your code to see if the matrix multiplication is even an issue. If it is, bbudge is right, you'll likely lose any performance gains by having to pass the array to PNaCl and back to JavaScript.

asm.js code runs in the same process and stack as JavaScript, so you may see benefits by using it. Take a look at http://jsperf.com/matrix-multiplication-with-asm-js/6. Unfortunately, there are no guarantees that asm.js will be performant on all browsers. If a browser doesn't support asm.js directly, it will be executed as plain JavaScript, which may end up being slower.

When [WebAssembly](http://webassembly.github.io/) is available, that will likely be your best bet.